# What are good references to self study persistent homology?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, soft-question, topological-data-analysis

I am a graduate student in mathematics interested in persistent homology. Can anyone recommend good books or resources to self study persistent homology?

I am taking a course in Algebraic Topology, studying the book by Hatcher.

Comment: I'm no expert in the subject, but this is a fantastic [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0bnG1Wavag) explaining the gist of it.

Comment: Aside from the important articles in that Video's description. You might like to begin with "Topology for Computer", Zomorodian. Although slightly outdated, it is very accessible!

Comment: Oops, I meant [Topology for Computing, Afra J. Zomorodian](http://www.amazon.com/Computing-Cambridge-Monographs-Computational-Mathematics/dp/0521136091). Sorry!

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I would expect that a solid background in algebraic topology would be more than helpful before attacking persistent homology.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a quick introduction, you can read this AMS survey.

- [*What is … Persistent Homology?* by Shmuel Weinberger](http://www.ams.org/notices/201101/rtx110100036p.pdf)

A basic notion in persistent homology is a *barcode*. The following article gives an introduction to the subject with an emphasis on shape recognition, and tells you what a barcode its.

- [*Barcodes: The Persistent Homology of Data* by Robert Ghrist](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/preprints/barcodes.pdf)

Here is another introductory survey article giving you more background material about the theory and implementation of persistent homology. This one also talks about some heavier stuff from algebraic topology, like spectral sequences.

- [*Persistent Homology – a Survey* by Herbert Edelsbrunner and John Harer](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~edels/Papers/2008-B-02-PersistentHomology.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few references, some old, some new:

- [*Topological Pattern Recognition for Point Cloud Data* by Gunnar Carlsson](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/BB0DA0F0EBD79809C563AF80B555A23C/S0962492914000051a.pdf/topological_pattern_recognition_for_point_cloud_data.pdf) – A foundational paper on the subject of topological data analysis, with a good exposition.
- [*A Brief History of Persistence* by Jose A. Perea](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03624.pdf) – A recent (2018) eleven page introduction that covers persistence modules and quiver representations.
- [Tamal K Dey's 2017 course on *Computational Topology and Data Analysis*](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~dey.8/course/CTDA/CTDA.html)
- [This question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/310384/64073) is quite insightful.